# Sampling from a Bayesian network with evidence in tensorflow-probability

Tags: bayesian-networks, tensorflow-probability

Is there an easy way to "observe" evidence and sample from the joint distribution in tensorflow-probability? In PyMC3, for example, the `Distribution` class has the `observed` parameter in its constructor, so one can easily condition on evidence (and run MCMC to get posterior samples).

There is some documentation related to Edward, but I couldn't figure it out for the simples case, such as:

```py
import tensorflow_probability.python.distributions as tfd
import tensorflow as tf

jdn = tfd.JointDistributionNamed(dict(
    dist_x=tfd.Categorical([0.2, 0.8], validate_args=True),
    dist_y=lambda dist_x: tfd.Categorical(probs=tf.gather([[0.1, 0.9],
                                                               [0.5, 0.5]], indices=dist_x))
))
# sample from joint
print(jdn.sample(100, seed=1234))

# now "observe" some variables
observed_variable = jdn.model.get('dist_x')
assert isinstance(observed_variable, tfd.Distribution)

observed_variable.?
```

Which is probably the simplest Bayesian network with two binary variables X and Y. The goal is to set evidence to either X or Y and sample from the posterior in order to estimate the probabilities.

(Obviously, one can use rejection sampling by sampling first unconditioned and then throw away samples not consistent with the evidence, but it would be fairly inefficient.)

Answer (score 1):

In general, posterior sampling is hard :)

To get an unnormalized target density for use in an MCMC scheme, you can do something like

```py
import tensorflow_probability.python.distributions as tfd
import tensorflow as tf
import functools

jdn = tfd.JointDistributionNamed(dict(
    x=tfd.Categorical([0.2, 0.8], validate_args=True),
    y=lambda dist_x: tfd.Categorical(probs=tf.gather([[0.1, 0.9],
                                                      [0.5, 0.5]], indices=x))
))

log_unnormalized_posterior = functools.partial(jdn.log_prob, x=data)
# ^-- this is a function of one variable (y), which is the (log) unnormalized
# posterior conditioned on `x=data`.
```

To get the actual posterior here, you'd need to evaluate this log probability function on all the possible `y` values, then normalize those. You can then feed those to a new Categorical, which would be the actual posterior. We don't have a canned way to do this in TFP, mainly because discrete enumeration is in general very expensive. For sampling from densities over continuous variables, we have some nice support for Hamiltonian Monte Carlo, which would follow essentially the same recipe as above, "clamping" the observed variables to some data to obtain an unnormalized target density and using that for MCMC.

Comment: Thanks Chris, maybe I'm trying to use the big hammer on a wrong nail. I know that the strengths of TFD are in Bayesian deep learning or hierarchical BNs with continuous densities. The examples I'm bringing up are super basic and easily solvable in pymc3 but given that pymc3 builds on Theano which is now discontinued, I'm trying to pick up the most promising tool to learn which is TFD as of now, I guess.

Comment: Sure! There's certainly nothing wrong with doing what you're trying to do, I hope my reply didn't read as discouraging :)